# Multiple audio players in Firefox

Tags: firefox, audio

I have a problem with multiple custom players in Firefox (52.6.0.6592 and others, with different outcome): only the last audio on page is playable. The weird thing is that everything works in Chrome and Opera (with ogg format). I assume it has something to do with playhead or timeline, since in some Firefox versions all audios are functioning, but playhead isn't moving. No errors in console, btw, except there was "margin-left parse error" at one point, but it stopped appearing after I reinstalled Firefox. Any suggestions?

Links: 
HTML: https://m-ch.ml/t/wakaba.html 
JS for players: https://m-ch.ml/t/audioPlayer/Pll.js 
CSS: https://m-ch.ml/t/audioPlayer/Pl.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself. For whatever reason in Firefox duration returns as zero when I try to get it through audio object. I've changed "ao.duration" to document.getElementById(audio-id), so now it works.